# How to compare two sheets and get the common rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a excel file which has two sheets and below is the first sheet and second sheet. I want to compare the two sheets (ex: each row of first sheet with with all the rows of second sheet ) and then get all the common/matching rows.( all the column values should be same in both rows). Please help me in figuring this out

```
Col-1  Col-2    Col-3
one    data11   data12
two    data21   date22
three  data31   data32
five   date49   data69


Col-1   Col-2   Col-3
one     data11  data12
two     data21  date22
three   data31  data36
five    date45  data69
```

So the end result should be matching rows i.e as below

```
Col-1 Col-2 Col-3
one data11  data12
two data21  date22
```

Comment: I have compared using TortoiseSVN freeware  by selecting the two excel files and it did an Amazing work

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP answered it in the comments

Comment: @Sukumar, why don't you put your solution in an answer and include a link to TortoiseSVN.  You're allowed to answer your own question.

Comment: @fixer1234 i had checked but one issue is that Tortoise is comparing first row in Sheet1 with first row in sheet 2 but not with all other rows in sheet2. So Tortoise is also not working as required. Any Ideas on this please about comparing between sheets

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. It has a Merge command that can handle this requirement:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/merge-queries-HA104149757.aspx

After selecting the three columns, I would check the option "Only include matching rows".

As your output requirement doesn't need any extra columns from sheet2, you could just Remove the "NewColumn" that will be added by the Merge, and leave it at that.